# Matter js: is there a way for a group of bodies to collide with each other and for another group: the last group is acting like a sensor?

Tags: javascript, game-physics, physics, matter.js

I would something like surviv.io : items on the ground (circles with weapon) collide with each other but for the players, items are only sensors. How can I do this?

I tried collisionFilter.category and mask, but the player is not detecting the circle body for an event.

[image]

Comment: Code as a [mcve] would be useful to see here so future visitors understand what you're dealing with. Related: [Matter.JS Detect collision between two static sensors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54379284/matter-js-detect-collision-between-two-static-sensors)

Comment: Haven't touched this project for 4 years and lost track of it. Sorry :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the question on the Matter.js GitHub (https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/691) and the creator suggest me to pin 2 bodies together (1 solid body and 1 sensor)

[image]

Comment: Can you explain how you pinned the body and sensor together?

Comment: It was 2 years ago and I lost this project, I believe I used [constraints](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Constraint.html) to pin the body and the sensor together. Don't forget to add a layer mask so the body and the sensor don't collide with each other. Good luck!