# Matter.JS Detect collision between two static sensors

Tags: javascript, react-native, p5.js, matter.js

I'm trying to add some circle bodies to my game world that can be moved around. I need to detect when they collide, but also let them pass trough.

I've tried to make the circles `isSensor` and `isStatic` - no collision detected.

I've tried to make them `isSensor` and NOT `isStatic` - collision detected but they fall trough the world because of the gravity/physics.

I've tried to remove the physics but no collision detected.

What to do?

Comment: Could you show your attempts so far? The code context makes it a lot easier to help because I can tweak your attempts rather than having to start from scratch, risking the answer being totally irrelevant to your use case.

Comment: Related: [Matter js: is there a way for a group of bodies to collide with each other and for another group: the last group is acting like a sensor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53323147/matter-js-is-there-a-way-for-a-group-of-bodies-to-collide-with-each-other-and-f) and [#691](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/691).